# AZ rest call fails but same working fine in postman

Tags: rest, azure-cli

I am calling AZ rest method to add new Agent pool like below. From POSTMAN I am able to make the call and with same request body and everything the call failing in az.

The command goes like below.

```
az REST --method post --url "https://dev.azure.com/${ORG}/${PROJECT}/_apis/distributedtask/queues?api-version=7.0" -
-body '{"name":"TEST_AGENT_POOL_22234222"}' --body '{"id":"667"}' --headers "Authorization: Bearer $azureAccessToken" "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on this, I found that the error message is related to the ***Json parsing***. It means the request body is not properly formatted. You can modify it as below.

`--body "{\"name\":\"newagentpool\",\"id\":\"667"}"`

```bash
az rest --method post --body "{\"name\":\"newagentpool\",\"id\":\"667"}"  --uri <URI>
```

[image]

And check the **CLI version** you are using. Try to update the version of Az CLI if it is not up to dated.

**`az version`:**

[image]

**`az upgrade`:**

[image]

This kind of error also shows when the generated token got expired. Try and generate the new bearer if required.

```bash
az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output tsv
```

Refer [Azure Citadel](https://www.azurecitadel.com/rest-api/cli/) article for more relevant information on `az rest` API calls.